# Adding Font-Awesome to Yii2 Via Composer

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I have Yii2 installed on my system, the exact version is 2.0.15.1. (basic not advanced template)

I wanted to add Font-Awesome via composer, the code to to this is:
composer require components/font-awesome

When I try to add it, I get errors, since I'm new to composer I don't really know what actions to take, but this project has many packages installed which I'm going to list here.

I will also list a capture of the error I'm getting in case someone can assist me on solving this, keep in mind I don't want to break any other package on this project due to versions.

Packages installed:

```
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip": "~2.0.5",         
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
        "hguenot/yii2-gsftp": "*",
        "ext-bz2": "*",
        "edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "^1.1.2",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "^1.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-nav-x": "*",
        "yii2mod/yii2-ftp": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*",
        "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "v1.5.0",        
        "xj/snoopy": "2.0.0",
        "vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension": "*",
        "hscstudio/yii2-export": "1.0.0",
        "omnilight/yii2-scheduling": "*",
        "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "*",
        "dts/ebay-sdk-php": "^7.0",
        "mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "*",
        "exeu/apai-io": "~2.0",
        "authorizenet/authorizenet": "1.9.2",
        "kop/yii2-scroll-pager": "dev-master",
        "alfallouji/dhl_api": "^0.2.10",
        "vinceg/usps-php-api": "^1.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.7.11",
        "jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper": "dev-master",
        "russ666/yii2-countdown": "^0.1.0",
        "dsposito/argo": "^2.0",
        "impgds/rocketshipit": "dev-master" ,
        "ujjwal/currency-converter":"2.2.*",
        "tawba/currency-converter": "^1.7",
        "bestbuy/bestbuy": "^1.0",
        "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^1.7",
        "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^0.2.1",
        "sorich87/bootstrap-tour": "*@dev",
        "mycademy/yii2-bootstrap-tour": "*@dev",
        "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet" : "*@dev",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "4.*",
        "dmore/chrome-mink-driver": "^2.6",
        "facebook/webdriver": "^1.6",
        "stichoza/google-translate-php": "^3.2",
        "docta/mercadolibre": "^1.0",
        "dejurin/php-google-translate-for-free": "^1.0",
        "viniciusgava/google-translate-api": "^2.0",
        "serps/search-engine-google": "^0.4.6",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^1.8",
        "serps/http-client-curl": "^0.2.3",
        "components/font-awesome": "^5.15"
        
        
        
    },
 
    
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7",
        "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "dev-master",
        "simpletest/simpletest": "^1.1"
        
    },
```

Error I'm getting:

[Capture of composer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apwdC.png)

Thanks in advace.

Comment: It looks like the package just hasn't updated to support composer 2.

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear to you? What have you tried to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

This error is in no way related to `components/font-awesome` - you need to update `yiisoft/yii2-composer` to at least v2.0.9 which is the first version where [the support for Composer 2 has been added](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer/issues/27). This can be done by running `composer update yiisoft/yii2-composer`

Comment: Thanks Nico, question, in case I run the above command specified and for some reason it breaks the system, is there a way to revert the changes back with composer?

Comment: Yes, just checkout the prior version from your version control. If you don't have any, you can copy `composer.lock` to a backup place before